# Get permission error when restarting Virtual Machine in Azure

Tags: windows, permissions, credentials, failed, reboot

Our network engineer left the company for another opportunity and I inherited the role of Network Engineer. I was trying to RDP to one of our Virtual Machine, but could never connect. I want to reboot the server, and every time i click on restart or stop, I get the following error:

Failed to restart the virtual machine 'DC-AZUREPOLK-02'. Error: The client 'XXXXXXXX@XXX.XXX' with object id 'a11ede69-8ab4-4a9a-82cb-c74fe972070d' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action' over scope 'RG-POLK-PROD/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/DC-AZUREPOLK-02'>DC-AZUREPOLK-02' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I'm fairly new to Azure and trying to find my way around and I don't know where to go to resolve this issue and looking for a little to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/issues/164#issuecomment-281696486):

> The service principal you are using doesn't have rights within that tenant.
>
> Tenants have subscriptions and service principals belong to tenants. Azure resource manager also exposes role based authorization for a given principal, which would give it rights on Azure resources. It appears the service principal doesn't have rights to read from that subscription.
>
> This is a really common issue. We've added a specific command in Azure CLI (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) to setup a service principal for automation with role based authorization already baked in.
>
> You want to use the `az ad sp create-for-rbac` command.